# On Tap and On Long Press not working properly

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to make a button that does two different things based on if you tap or if you long press on it. The following code seems like it should work, but only the long press event works. if I just tap it, I see the animation for the button being pressed, but it doesn't do anything until I long press on it.

```
                Button(action: {}) {
                    Image("no_image_taken")
                        .resizable()
                        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
                        .cornerRadius(10)
                        .gesture(TapGesture()
                            .onEnded({_ in self.showImagePicker = false}))
                        .gesture(LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 1)
                            .onEnded({_ in self.showImagePicker = true}))
                }.sheet(isPresented: self.$showImagePicker) {
                    PhotoCaptureView(useExistingPhoto: self.$useExistingPhoto, showImagePicker: self.$showImagePicker, image: self.$optionalImage)
                }
```

I based my code on the answer given [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284994/swiftui-how-to-handle-both-tap-long-press-of-button), but mine still isn't working.

Comment: Did you try it without Button? Just use Image instead of Button

Comment: @Mac3n I had not, but that did in fact work. If you want to make it an answer I'll be happy to give you credit for it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just put your gestures actions on Image and there is s no need to be on Button in this purpose.