# Detect "On Tap End" on Button

Tags: swiftui

I'm developing a simple MIDI keyboard. Each piano key is a button. As soon you press it, it sends a "MIDI note ON" signal to a virtual device:

```swift
Button(action: {
    MidiDevice.playNote("C")
}) { 
    Image(systemName: "piano-white-key")
}
```

It works fine. The latency is good and the user can play the key for just a fraction of a second or hold the button for longer notes. Now, how do I intercept the "user has lifted her finger" action in order to immediately send the `MidiDevice.stopNote("C")` event?

Comment: Is anything here useful to you? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58284994/swiftui-how-to-handle-both-tap-long-press-of-button

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is possible solution (as far as I understood your goal) - to use `ButtonStyle` to detect `isPressed` state. Standard `Button` sends actions of tap UP, so we just add action handler for tap DOWN.

Tested with Xcode 12.4 / iOS 14.4

```
struct ButtonPressHandler: ButtonStyle {
    var action: () -> ()
    func makeBody(configuration: Self.Configuration) -> some View {
        configuration.label
            .foregroundColor(configuration.isPressed ? 
                  Color.blue.opacity(0.7) : Color.blue)   // just to look like system
            .onChange(of: configuration.isPressed) {
                if $0 {
                    action()
                }
            }
    }
}

struct TestButtonPress: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(">> tap up")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "piano-white-key")
        }
        .buttonStyle(ButtonPressHandler {
            print("<< tap down")
        })
    }
}
```

Comment: This is beautiful

Comment: I'd love SwiftUI to handle this natively, but this is perfect, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

In addition to Asperi's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66338313/8697793), you can create an extension which will make it more *SwiftUI-style*:

```
extension Button {
    func onTapEnded(_ action: @escaping () -> Void) -> some View {
        buttonStyle(ButtonPressHandler(action: action))
    }
}
```

```
struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Button(action: {
            print(">> tap up")
        }) {
            Image(systemName: "piano-white-key")
        }
        .onTapEnded {
            print("<< tap down")
        }
    }
}
```