# Is there a way to make a button have two separate actions depending on if it’s been tapped or long pressed?

Tags: ios, swift, button, gesture

I’m trying to make a button in Swift and make it so it does two separate actions depending on if you’ve tapped it, or long pressed it. But I also want it to open a page ONLY once you’ve released the button after holding it, and i can’t figure that out anywhere. Any help will be greatly appreciated!!

I tried using the `.TapGesture` and a `.simultaneousGesture`(LongPressGesture) and it didn’t work.

Comment: This post might help: [SwiftUI: how to handle BOTH tap & long press of button?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58284994/20386264)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`LongPressGesture` ends when the duration of the press has reached `minimumDuration`, not when the finger is lifted (end of the touch).

`DragGesture` does end at the end of the touch, so you can use it to detect releasing the button, and use an additional `LongPressGesture` to set a flag to true once it ended. You would then do one of the two different things depending on the flag.

For example, here is an example where the button prints "Tap Action" when the touch lasts less than 2 seconds, and "Long Press Action" when the touch lasts more than 2 seconds.

```
@State private var isLongPress = false

...

.simultaneousGesture(
    DragGesture(minimumDistance: 0).onEnded { _ in
        if isLongPress {
            print("Long Press Action")
        } else {
            print("Tap Action")
        }
        isLongPress = false
    }
)
.simultaneousGesture(
    LongPressGesture(minimumDuration: 2, maximumDistance: .infinity)
        .onEnded { _ in
            isLongPress = true
        }
)
```

The max duration of a "tap" (as detected by `TapGesture`) is not documented, so you can't exactly replicate the behaviour of `onTapGesture` with this approach.

Comment: Thank you so much!! This acctually worked for me! You're a life safer!! The last thing I need to figure out is how to make it do something while pressing and holding the button. hmm

Comment: @JJTrejo you can do that in `onChange` of the drag gesture - it will be called every frame while you are touching the screen.

Comment: thank you! i put the check mark on there since you've basically answered every question i have!