# SwiftUI TextField does not work after adding gesture

Tags: swiftui, textfield

After adding a combined gesture to a view, a TextField inside the view would no longer respond when I would tap into it to change the text.  I discovered this after adding a custom combined gesture - where I used a long press to start things before dragging.  (Note: things still worked if just a drag gesture was added.  Not sure what is particularly different between these two cases.)

The combined gesture:

```
let combined = longPressGesture.simultaneously(with: dragGesture)
```

The gesture was added to the view with:

```
.gesture(combined)
```

Answer (score 2):

I got things to work by adding an onTapGesture{} to the TextField.  Didn’t have to put anything into the action.  Seems like a side effect whose behavior could change in the future.  Appreciate any comments on if this makes sense or other ways to handle.

```
TextField(“Enter Text”, text: $myText)
                        .textFieldStyle(RoundedBorderTextFieldStyle())
                        .onTapGesture {}
```

Comment: Update:  I had the TextField inside a horizontal ScrollView.  Discovered I had some other things inside the ScrollView not responding “properly” as well.  Instead add the “empty” .onTapGesture{} to the HStack inside the ScrollView.  Could then remove it from individual items inside the ScrollView/HStack - and make the code cleaner.

Answer (score 1):

In case one would have this issue with a drag gesture, you can set the minimumDistance. This would still register the tap on the textfield to edit it.

```
DragGesture(minimumDistance: 30, coordinateSpace: .global)
```

[Adding a drag gesture in SwiftUI to a View inside a ScrollView blocks the scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57700396/adding-a-drag-gesture-in-swiftui-to-a-view-inside-a-scrollview-blocks-the-scroll)